# android Async - Update Dialog Message in loop

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, dialog

I am trying to update the message in my alert dialog. I want the dialog  show the updated percent of graph completion.

---

Please wait...
The graphs are loading ...

### 0% completed

I figured out how to get the percent of each loop iteration, I am having a hard time updating the dialog to the correct percent. Thanks in advance!!!!

//my xml textview object

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/percentloaded"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="The graphs are loading...\n0% Completed"
     android:layout_gravity="right"
     android:visibility="invisible"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"  />
```

//how I call the async inside of my in create function

```
 new MyAsync().execute();
```

//my onCreate()

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_network_showcharts);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
    // fun little snippet that prevents users from taking screenshots
    // on ICS+ devices :-)
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    //Toast.makeText(NetworkAllInformation_ShowChart.this, "Please wait for graphs to finish loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NetworkAllInformation_ShowChart.this);
   cycleDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CycleDateAnswer);
    cycleDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CycleDayAnswer);
    cycleDailyUsage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CycleUsageAnswer);
    cycleOverallUsage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalUsageAnswer);
    percentLoaded = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentloaded);


    stringofZero = "0";

    plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

    alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

     final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


     year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  

    currentDate = (month+1) +"-" +day+ "-"+ year;   


     theNumberOfDaysToCompare = day;

    intObj = new Integer(theNumberOfDaysToCompare); 

    intNumberOfMaxGBsAccepted = 0;
    numObj = (Number)intObj;  

     series1Numbers = new Number[(Integer) numObj];
     series2Numbers = new Number[(Integer) numObj];
     series3Numbers = new Number[(Integer) numObj];

     handler = new Handler();


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query0 = ParseQuery.getQuery("ClientCompanyInfo");
    query0.whereEqualTo("SiteID", ShowSatellitesActivity.IDchosen);
    query0.addAscendingOrder("SiteID");
    query0.setLimit(1000);
    query0.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("UsagePlan"));



         List<ParseObject> results0 = null;
            try {
                results0 = query0.find();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


             System.out.println("query0 size: "+results0.size());
             for (ParseObject data : results0) {
                  // This does not require a network access.

                Integer.parseInt(data.getString("UsagePlan"));
                System.out.println("the usage plan is: "+Integer.parseInt(data.getString("UsagePlan")) );

                if(Integer.parseInt(data.getString("UsagePlan")) >=1 )
                {
                    System.out.println("The usage plan is a set number");
                    intNumberOfMaxGBsAccepted = Integer.parseInt(data.getString("UsagePlan"));

                } //ends if

             }//ends for loop 



            new MyAsync().execute();



    sum = 0;



} //ends on create
```

//my Async Task

```
private static class MyAsync extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, String> {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {

       super.onPreExecute();

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Please wait...");

        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(percentLoaded.getText());

        // create alert dialog
        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();



      }


      protected static void onProgressUpdate(Integer progress) {


              alertDialog.setMessage("The graphs are loading...\n"+progress[0]+"% Completed");
        alertDialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("onProgressUpdate: "+progress[0]);


         }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

          System.out.println("onPostExecute: "+result);

          alertDialog.setMessage("The graphs are loading...\n"+result+"% Completed");

        }





    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                incrementor = 0;
                for ( int i = 0; i<day; i++){ 

                     //get information about the user
                     ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UsageCalculator");
                     query.whereEqualTo("SiteID", ShowSatellitesActivity.IDchosen);
                     query.addAscendingOrder("SiteID");
                     query.setLimit(1000);
                     query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {



                            public void done(ParseObject dailyUsage, ParseException e) {

                                if (e == null) {

                                    dayString = (1+incrementor);
                                     System.out.println("Day number: "+Integer.toString(dayString)); 

                                     getThePercent =  Integer.toString((int) ((100 / (float) day) * dayString));
                                        System.out.println(getThePercent);


                                        Integer percentInt = Integer.valueOf((100 /day) * dayString);

                                        try{

                                    publishProgress(percentInt);
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                        } catch(Exception e1){
                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        }


                                     //start
                                 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("UsageCalculator");
                                 query2.whereEqualTo("monthString", String.valueOf(month+1)); //current month
                                 query2.whereEqualTo("SiteID", dailyUsage.getString("SiteID")); //the selected ID
                                 query2.whereEqualTo("yearString", String.valueOf(year)); //current year
                                 query2.whereEqualTo("dayString", Integer.toString(dayString)); //incremented through to have every day
                                 query2.addAscendingOrder("SiteID");
                                 query2.setLimit(1000);
                                 query2.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("dataUsedString", "usageDate")); //take the information out of the date and usage columns
                                 List<ParseObject> results = null;

                                try {
                                    results = query2.find();

                                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }


                                 System.out.println("query8 size: "+results.size());
                                 for (ParseObject data : results) {
                                      // This does not require a network access.

                                      myArray.add(data.getString("dataUsedString"));
                                 }

                                 //the last day reached
                                    if(myArray.size() == day-1){
                                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                                        plot.clear(); //erase the old plot
                                        updateGraphValues(); //get values of graph
                                        updateGraphBackground(); //set the values to the graph
                                        plot.redraw(); //redraw the plot with the correct values
                                    }
                               incrementor++;

                                } //if the exception handler is null



                                else {
                                    Log.d("showChart", "Error: " + e.getMessage()); //if their is an exception
                                }

                            } //ends the done




                        }); //ends the query

                        } //ends the for loop








        return "";
        }



     }
```

//other function calls

```
    private static void updateGraphValues() {

      for (int i = 0; i<myArray.size(); i++){

            usageValue = Double.parseDouble(myArray.get(i));

            //daily usage array
            series2Numbers[i] = usageValue;
            //total usage sumation array
            series1Numbers[i] = (usageValue+increasingSum);
            //the max value 
            series3Numbers[i] = intNumberOfMaxGBsAccepted;
            vector.add((double) i);
            vector.add(Math.sin(i));

            //keeping a running sum
            if(usageValue!=0) { increasingSum= increasingSum+usageValue; }
        }

        increasingSum = 0;

} // ends updating the graph value function

private static void updateGraphBackground() {

    // Turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
    series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
            Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),          // SimpleXYSeries takes a List so turn our array into a List
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, // Y_VALS_ONLY means use the element index as the x value
            "Total");                             // Set the display title of the series

    // same as above
   series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series2Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Daily");
   series3 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series3Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Max");


    series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(51, 51, 255), 0, Color.rgb(51, 153, 255), null);


    series1Format.getFillPaint().setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    series1Format.getFillPaint().setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);  
    series1Format.getFillPaint().setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10) );
    series1Format.getFillPaint().setAntiAlias(true); 
    series1Format.getFillPaint().setStrokeWidth(8);


    // same as above:
    //daily green
    series2Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(51, 255, 153), 0, Color.rgb(153, 255, 204), null);

    series2Format.getFillPaint().setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    series2Format.getFillPaint().setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);  
    series2Format.getFillPaint().setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10) );
    series2Format.getFillPaint().setAntiAlias(true); 
    series2Format.getFillPaint().setStrokeWidth(8);

    series3Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(255, 51, 51), 0, 0, null);

    series3Format.getFillPaint().setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    series3Format.getFillPaint().setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);  
    series3Format.getFillPaint().setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10) );
    series3Format.getFillPaint().setAntiAlias(true); 
    series3Format.getFillPaint().setStrokeWidth(8);


    // add a new series' to the xyplot:
    plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format); //this one has to be first to that the domain and range can be found for this series
    plot.addSeries(series2, series2Format);
    plot.addSeries(series3, series3Format);

    // reduce the number of range labels
    plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(1);
    plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelOrientation(45);

    plot.calculateMinMaxVals();
    minXy=new PointF(plot.getCalculatedMinX().floatValue(),plot.getCalculatedMinY().floatValue());
    maxXY=new PointF(plot.getCalculatedMaxX().floatValue(),plot.getCalculatedMaxY().floatValue());

   // plot.setClickable(true);

    //NOTE about XYPlotZoomPan: when an OnTouchListener is set, zooming is disabled. Subclass to avoid it.
    plot.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {


            //the begin of finding a point touched, then drawing two lines, and labeling the lines
            touchX = me.getX();
            touchY = me.getY();
            widget = plot.getGraphWidget();
            gridRect = widget.getGridRect();
            if(gridRect.contains(touchX, touchY)){ //Check the touch event is in the grid
                XYSeries xyData = plot.getSeriesSet().iterator().next();
                long targetValX = Math.round(widget.getXVal(touchX));
                System.out.println("Touched at " + touchX + ", " + touchY + ". Target val X: " + targetValX);

                if(plot.getSeriesSet().size() > 1){
                    System.out.println("More than one series in plot. Using only the first one");
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < xyData.size(); ++i){
                    long currValX = xyData.getX(i).longValue();
                    long currValY = xyData.getY(i).longValue();

                    //Calculate the range value of the closest domain value (assumes xyData is sorted in ascending X order)
                    if(currValX >= targetValX){
                        long currDiff = currValX - targetValX; 
                        if(prevValX != null && (targetValX - prevValX) < currDiff){
                            targetValY = xyData.getY(i-1).longValue();
                        }else{
                            targetValY = currValY;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    prevValX = currValX;
                }
                if(targetValY != null){
                    long maxValY = plot.getCalculatedMaxY().longValue();
                    long minValY = plot.getCalculatedMinY().longValue();
                    System.out.println("Target Y Value"+targetValY);
                    float pixelPosY = gridRect.top + ValPixConverter.valToPix((double)targetValY, (double)minValY, (double)maxValY, (float)gridRect.height(), true);
                    System.out.println("Pixel Pos Y: "+pixelPosY);

                    Number numberForDaily =  series2Numbers[ (int)targetValX];

                    widget.setDomainCursorPosition(touchX);
                    System.out.println("Touch X: "+touchX);

                    plot.getGraphWidget().setSize(new SizeMetrics(
                            0, SizeLayoutType.FILL,
                            0, SizeLayoutType.FILL)

                            );


                    Paint paintForText = new Paint();
                    paintForText.setColor(Color.BLACK);

                    Paint paintForTextBackroud = new Paint();
                    paintForTextBackroud.setColor(Color.WHITE);


                    widget.setCursorLabelPaint(paintForText);
                    widget.setCursorLabelBackgroundPaint(paintForTextBackroud);
                    widget.getDomainLabelPaint().setTextSize(20);
                    widget.getRangeLabelPaint().setTextSize(20);
                    widget.getCursorLabelPaint().setTextSize(25);

                    System.out.println("Cursor is at = "+ targetValX + " " + targetValY);

                    getTheStartDate();

                    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month + 1, day);
                    Integer theNumberOfTheStartDay = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

                   //the offset
                    Integer addingTheDates = (theNumberOfTheStartDay + (int)targetValX);

                    //convert number to a date which is readable
                   GregorianCalendar gcDate = new GregorianCalendar();
                   gcDate.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, addingTheDates);


                   //if the day of the month is less than 10
                   //add a zero to the front of it so that the string can be ordered
                   if(gcDate.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)<10){
                       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                       sb.append("0");
                       sb.append(gcDate.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                       fixZeroInDate = sb.toString();
                   }else{
                       fixZeroInDate= String.valueOf(gcDate.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                   }


                   String stringOfFinalCycleDate=
                           (gcDate.get((GregorianCalendar.MONTH)))+"/"+
                         fixZeroInDate+"/"+
                          gcDate.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);



                   //UPDATING THE TEXTVIEWS BASED ON BUTTON TAP
                   cycleDate.setText(stringOfFinalCycleDate); //cycle date

                    cycleDay.setText(Long.toString(targetValX)); //cycle day

                   cycleDailyUsage.setText( numberForDaily.toString());//usage of single cycle day

                   System.out.println("Start time now");
                   //do math to get the running total of usage
                   findtheUsageSum(stringOfFinalCycleDate);
                   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
                   cycleOverallUsage.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(usageSumOnClick))); //overall usage by the cycle day
                 System.out.println("How much time has passed?");

                }else{
                    System.out.println("Couldn't find the closest range to the selected domain coordinate");
                }

                plot.invalidate();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Touched outside the plot grid");
            }

            return false;
        }

        private void findtheUsageSum(String stringOfFinalCycleDate) {

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query3 = ParseQuery.getQuery("UsageCalculator");
             query3.whereEqualTo("SiteID", ShowSatellitesActivity.IDchosen);
             query3.addAscendingOrder("SiteID");
             query3.setLimit(10000);
             query3.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("usageDate", stringOfFinalCycleDate);
             query3.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("dataUsedString", "usageDate"));
             List<ParseObject> results1 = null;
            try {
                results1 = query3.find();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

             usageSumOnClick = 0;
             System.out.println("query3 size: "+results1.size());
             for (ParseObject data : results1) { 
                  // looping for all the dates and usage

                  System.out.println("data used: "+data.getString("dataUsedString"));
                  System.out.println("on date: "+data.getString("usageDate"));
                  usageSumOnClick = usageSumOnClick + Double.parseDouble(data.getString("dataUsedString"));

             } //ends for loop


        } //ends find the usage function

        private void getTheStartDate() {
             final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

             year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
             month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
             day = 1;  

                    startDate = (month+1) +"-" +day+ "-"+ year;   

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is/isn't happening? Is `onProgressUpdate()` even being called? And you really need to clean up that code so it is more readable

Comment: onProgressUpdateIs() is being called, it just is not updating the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `onProgressUpdate` method, that the AsyncTask provides you, don't create your own.

Also, don't call `onProgressUpdate` yourself! This is a callback method that is used by the system to provide you a callback to your UI Thread. If you call it directly, the code will run inside the background Thread, where you can't update the UI.  Instead, use `publishProgress`.

Edit: to be able to pass a proper value into `publishProgress`, you also need to specify the generic type on extending AsyncTask (the second generic type is the one for the progress).

Try it like this:

```
private static class MyAsync extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, String> {
....

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    alertDialog.setMessage("The graphs are loading...\n"+progress[0]+"% Completed");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    incrementor = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i<day; i++){ 
        publishProgress(getThePercent);
        ....
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am having a problem where I can't pass anything into my publishProgress() function. Do you know how I can allow publishProgress() to take in an argument?

Comment: Change `extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>`  to `extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, String>`

Comment: Changing what my AsyncTask extends helped me add an argument into    'onProgressUpdate(), so THANK YOU!!! I am having trouble now where the 'onProgressUpdate()' is being called/loaded after all of my charts have already loaded (which makes it useless because the alert dialog disapears after the charts load and it never makes it to my alert dialog). Is there any way to have the dialog update correctly on time??? THANKS!

Comment: I tried to use a sleep timer, but I am still having no luck.  :(

Comment: Do you do something in the UI Thread while this task is running?

Comment: I query my database from Parse.com and I call other functions to build the graphs. But I do not start any new threads. Do you need me to post more of my code?

Comment: Yup, but you do something after starting the AsyncTask, other than waiting for it? Yes, please post more of the code, so that I can see for myself..

Comment: I updated my code to include querying my database on Parse. In the loop: my LogCat prints out the **onPostExecute()**, query size, followed by the day number, followed by the percent completed. After it completed the loop then the **onProgressUpdate()** is called displaying all of the percentages. Do you see anywhere that I create a separate thread? Also **onPostExecute()** is triggered before my **onProgressUpdate()** is executed. I think that something is wrong with that... How do I make the **onPostExecute()** run last or maybe the question is how do I make everything else happen first?

Comment: Did you remove the `static` from `onProgressUpdate` in your current code? And plase add the code that is called after `new MyAsync().execute();`.

Comment: I posted my code from my onCreate function where my call to my AsyncTask class is made. I am having an error setting my **onProgressUpdate()** to be static. My class **MyAsync** is already static.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding why the **onPostExecute()** is not being called after the **doInBackground()** finishes. And is there a way to pause the **doInBackground()** so that the **onProgressUpdate()** can complete it's task before the doInBackground continues? Is this what a static function **onProgressUpdateDo()** would solve?

Comment: No, no static, you need to `@Override` these methods correctly for them to be called! Add the `@Override` annotation to them and see if it marks it as an error or not, if it marks it as an error, you don't override the method correctly and therefore it is understandable that it is not beeing called.

Comment: I added '@Override' above onPreExecute(), onProgressUpdate(), onPostExecute(), and doInBackground(). But it is still executing in the order of onPreExecute() --> onPostExecute() --> doInBackground() --> onProgressUpdate(). And only the first onProgressUpdate() is being called correctly. All others are being executed after doInBackground() finishes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't find anything that could result in this behaviour. Try to implement the updating of the progress in a small example, and if that works, maybe that helps you to find the error.